# applicationSettings for a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, web-config

I know similar flavors of this question has been asked before, but I am asking something a little different. I know how to use applicationSettings and such, but what I am trying to do is to make it into a config. i.e., I have a web application which as a reference to a class library. This class library has a reference to a web service. In doing that, it created a .settings file. When I am using this class library in the web application, everything works fine locally. However, in staging and production, I would like to have different URLs for the web service - the only way to do that seems to take the applicationSettings section, and put it in the web.config of the web application project. I'm trying to avoid muddying up the web.config, so is there a way to have this applicationSettings section in another files referenced by the web.config?

Comment: See [web.config transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <appsSettings configSource="appSettings.config" />
```

This moves the whole app settings section to a separate file.

Comment: but thats for "appSettings" - "applicationSettings" work differently, no?

Comment: True but the same rule applies, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821735/moving-settings-to-another-config-file